# Partial Differential Equation with Self-similar Solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a heat equation to be solved for in the form of
$$u_{t}= u_{xx}+u_{yy} $$
for $t = [0,+\infty)$ and $0<x<1$, $0<y<1 $ and $u=u(x,y,t)$
and following B.C:
$$
u(0,0,t)=0
$$
$$
u(1,1,t)=1
$$
I work out the solution roughly using the following procedure:

1. $u(x,y,t)=f(\xi,\eta)$, with $\xi = \frac{x}{t}$ and $\eta = \frac{y}{t}$

   Obtain PDE as:
   $$
   -(\xi f_\xi+\eta f_\eta)=f_{\xi\xi}+f_{\eta\eta}
   $$
   So, my question is

What is the appropriate way to solve this PDE ?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: This approach does not work in this case, for many reasons. Here is one: If a solution could have this form, then it would follow that $f(\xi,\xi) = 0$ for all $\xi$ by setting $x = y = 1$. Therefore also $u(x,x,t) = 1$ for all $0 < x < 1$ and all $t$. This would imply a discontinuity of the solution at $x = y = 0$ for all $t$.